# How to trigger a stereo camera on Gazebo Ignition with ROS2?

Tags: gazebo-camera, gazebo-ignition

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I'd like to trigger a stereo acquisition from ROS Galactic with Gazebo Ignition (Fortress).
I don't find any documentation. Could someone provide me an example ?
I've found https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/galactic/gazebo_plugins/include/gazebo_plugins/gazebo_ros_camera.hpp but I'm not sure if those plugins are for ignition or gazebo classic...

Thanks in advance

#### Update

Ignition plugins are here: https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/. Sensors have been fused into a single Sensor.cc.
To create a stereo camera you need two  tags with type "camera" as described here: https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/3b6c0f2a0bc71c5ff391852615609deec3c03674/src/systems/sensors/Sensors.cc#L739-L770

The Load() function parses the  tag: https://github.com/gazebosim/sdformat/blob/a51a76edd3b5d423b24034c4288fcda1d122c700/src/Camera.cc#L201-L404

To trigger cameras, you need to set the  tag to true and give a <trigger_topic>.
In the end, my urdf looks like this:

```
<sensor type="camera" name="right">
  <update_rate>10.0</update_rate>
  <always_on>true</always_on>
  <ignition_frame_id>camera_link_optical</ignition_frame_id>
  <pose>0 -0.12 0 0 0 0</pose>
  <topic>/model/mmx/stereo_camera/right/image_raw</topic>
  <camera name="right">
    <triggered>true</triggered>
    <trigger_topic>/trigger</trigger_topic>
    <horizontal_fov>1.3962634</horizontal_fov>
    <image>
        <width>600</width>
        <height>600</height>
        <format>R8G8B8</format>
    </image>
    <clip>
        <near>0.02</near>
        <far>300</far>
    </clip>
  </camera>
</sensor>

<sensor type="camera" name="left">
  <topic>/model/mmx/stereo_camera/left/image_raw</topic>
  <update_rate>10.0</update_rate>
  <always_on>true</always_on>
  <ignition_frame_id>mmx/camera_link_optical</ignition_frame_id>
  <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
  <camera name="left">
    <triggered>true</triggered>
    <trigger_topic>/trigger</trigger_topic>
    <horizontal_fov>1.3962634</horizontal_fov>
    <image>
        <width>600</width>
        <height>600</height>
        <format>R8G8B8</format>
    </image>
    <clip>
        <near>0.02</near>
        <far>300</far>
    </clip>
  </camera>
</sensor>
```

There is no message on the topic  `ign topic -t /model/mmx/stereo_camera/left/image_raw -e` which means the camera is in triger mode (not constantly streaming messages on the topic).

But the trigger_topic doesn't appear when I list topics with `ign topic -l`
And if I pusblish a message on the trigger_topic with `ign topic -t "/trigger" -m ignition.msgs.Empty -p " "`, cameras are not triggered (still no image message).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28388/how-to-trigger-a-stereo-camera-on-gazebo-ignition-with-ros2-?/) by [Clement](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/84310/clement/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-08-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) on 2022-08-16**:
The link you provided is ROS1.

Would this link big helpful for you? https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz/tree/foxy/ros_ign_gazebo_demos

Instead of Foxy, use Galactic

**Comment by [Clement](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/84310/clement/) on 2022-08-16**:
Indeed it was the old gazebo plugins. The new ones are https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim. It seems that all the sensors have been fused into a single sensor: https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/tree/ign-gazebo6/src/systems/sensors. But I can't make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

OK it works...
I found this page https://community.gazebosim.org/t/new-releases-2022-06-28-fortress/1486 on which there is a screenshot of a trigger command:

[image: image description]

So the issue was that I wasn't sending a Boolean message.
The command should have been: `ign topic -t "/trigger" -m Boolean -p "data: true" -n 1`

---

Originally posted by [Clement](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/84310/clement/) with karma: 3 on 2022-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Clement](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/84310/clement/) on 2022-08-17**:
I have another question, is gazebo ignition being abandoned?
There is no documentation at all.
It tooks me almost two days to figure how how to create a stereo bench and trigger a pair of images and it's only by chance.
Are people all moving to Webots ?